# Where are the ##teamcity[... messages coming from in Pycharm with pytest run/debug logs?

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, pytest

I do not have teamcity or teamcity-messages installed.

The test runner is pytest.

They do carry useful information. Just want to know where they are coming from.

```
Python 2.7.9 in pyenv
PyCharm 2019.1.2 Pro
Build #PY-191.7141.48
Macbook pro Mojave
Pytest 4.5.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [`teamcity.messages.TeamcityServiceMessages`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pycharm/teamcity/messages.py#L46) wrapper object, as used in the [`pytest_plugin.py`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pycharm/teamcity/pytest_plugin.py) module. Search for `self.teamcity` usages, for example

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(self, session, config, items):
    self.teamcity.testCount(len(items))
```

reports the total amount of collected tests for progress calculation etc.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help!